# Did Deadpool rescue all of the X-Force?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2

<sub>Note: This is basically all spoilers. If someone has a good way to apply the spoiler markdown (I ended up putting almost the whole body in markdown) please do so.</sub>

In the mid-credits scene we see Deadpool receive a time travel device similar to Cable's and then proceed to fix some of the past wrongs that occurred during the movie.

One of these fixes is stopping Peter (the normal guy) from dying trying to save Zeitgeist from a wood chipper. This would imply that Zeitgeist still gets killed by the wood chipper as if he didn't Peter would not need to be saved...

**So are we to assume that Deadpool only saved Peter or did he save the other/all members of the X-Force?**

(I also read something on another question that it might have been confirmed that an X-Force movie is in the works, so I would assume they would need to be alive somehow.)

Comment: Another question. Why *didn't* he use the time travel device to save Vanessa?

Comment: @MartinCarney Did you see the full film?

Comment: I watched *Once Upon A Deadpool* rather than Deadpool 2.

Comment: @MartinCarney Was that the PG-13 version? If so, it seems like that is a major difference....

Comment: It is the PG-13 re-cut, yes.

Comment: He did save Vanessa.  In both versions...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## No

In an interview Ryan Reynolds states that Deadpool only saves Peter out of the X-Force members.

> "So I love that he just completely ignores this marquee cast that he could've saved of useful and wonderful superheroes," Reynolds explained, "but instead went back and saved [Peter]."
>
> But according to Reynolds, that choice to save Peter actually has a deeper meaning behind it, when you look at one of the film's earlier sequences.
>
> "Well here's the thing though, I always felt that it was important to save Peter, just because in the helicopter before we jump, I say to him 'I'd never let anything happen to you, sugar bear. I'm just saying this to impress the other guys.' And we all jump out of the thing." Reynolds continued. "So I felt like that was a promise that Wade made early on in the movie, and it was nagging him, so he went back and got Peter."
>
> <sub>[comicbook, 'Deadpool 2': Ryan Reynolds Reveals Why Deadpool Didn't Save Everyone](https://comicbook.com/marvel/2018/05/23/deadpool-2-x-force-deaths-peter-retcon-ryan-reynolds/)</sub>

Although Paul Wernick has stated because Deadpool has Cable's time travel device they might bring the characters back if they want to.

> "I’d say yes, [we were nervous about the fan reaction]." Wernick revealed. "Absolutely. Terrified. These are characters that childhoods grow up on. So the idea that Shatterstar just jumps out of a plane and dies, then yeah. But our test with Deadpool is, if you couldn’t do it in another superhero movie then you SHOULD do it in Deadpool. It’s like we’re given the license to push the boundaries and it’s a boundary we definitely worry about. It’s shocking and crazy and funny and we built our whole marketing campaign around these guys. People are coming to the movie thinking these guys are gonna team up and be part of this X-Force and in an instant they’re all dead! Comedy trumped better judgment."
>
> But of course, the film essentially built in a way for any of these original team members to return later on, should they make their way into Drew Goddard's proposed X-Force film.
>
> "Here’s the beauty of it," Wernick added, "Deadpool has gotten hold of Cable’s time-travel device so we could always bring back any of these guys if we wanted to."
>
> <sub>[comicbook, 'Deadpool 2' Actors Shot Footage Just for the Trailers to Fool the Audience](https://comicbook.com/marvel/2018/05/20/deadpool-2-x-force-trailer-movie-scenes-bedlam-shatterstar/)</sub>